# When writing assembly to which memory address should I start writing?

Tags: solidity, evm, assembly

when should you start writing to memory address mstore(0x40, x) and when to mstore(0x80, x)?

Some contracts that I've seen, for example this one https://github.com/Rari-Capital/solmate/blob/main/src/utils/SafeTransferLib.sol

They use the 0x40 memory address, but others use the 0x80.

What is the difference, and which one should I use?

Thanks a lot hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking the question, you probably should write at the address returned by `mload(0x40)`, you can read more about the solidity memory layout in [the documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/internals/layout_in_memory.html).

This is what the code that you linked is doing :

```
// Get a pointer to some free memory.
let freeMemoryPointer := mload(0x40)

// Write the abi-encoded calldata into memory, beginning with the function selector.
mstore(freeMemoryPointer, 0x23b872dd00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
```

Writing directly to `0x80` or any other fixed address is a possible optimization (because don't pay additional gas for an `mload(0x40)` instruction) if you either :

- Know that this is the current value at `memory[0x40]` (`0x80` is the initial value stored at `0x40`)
- Don't care about overwriting allocating memory / respecting solidity memory model. (proxy do this for instance by writing an arbitrary amount of data starting at address `0x00`)

In any case, if you intend to return / use the any allocated memory space, make sure to mark that memory as allocated by incrementing the free memory pointer :

```
// Allocate 32 bytes of memory by :
// taking the value of the free memory pointer : mload(0x40)
// incrementing it by 0x20 (32) : add(mload(0x40), 0x20)
// writing the resulting value to 0x40 : mstore(0x40, ...)
mstore(0x40, add(mload(0x40), 0x20))
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Oh, and just to clarify. 0x40 isn't a constant address but it will always give you a free memory pointer? So if the first 256 bytes are taken in memory it will point you to the next free one? Thanks

Comment: No, `0x40` is constant and part of solidity memory model. At `memory[0x40]` there is the free memory address. As long as solidity's memory model is respected you can safely read `memory[0x40]` and use the value stored there. This is the value at `memory[0x40]` that will change depending on previous allocations. Not sure if that's clear enough ?